# Placing students as far as possible to minimize cheating

Tags: algorithm, search, optimization, graph, puzzle

Given a matrix of size m * n, place k students in such a way so that cheating in an exam could be minimized.

**My approach:** 
Consider a m * n matrix, Place 1st student at X, (X= any cell in the given matrix). For next student do a BFS, for each empty cell, calculate its remoteness (R). For R, we can start with value t=max(m, n), and at each next cell we encounter at same level in BFS, we add t-level. And store this cell if R is minimum till now. Finally put next student in cell with minimum R value. Repeat this for all the students(k).

**Optimisation:** If we reach a cell with R greater than what we had till now, ignore it.

**How can we optimise it ?

Are there better algorithms to do this ?

Has my starting cell X has something to do with final answer ?**

For example if its 5x5 mat, and I put first student at 0x0 or if I start with 2x2, which one would be better for generalised k ? (obviously for k=2, 0x0 would be better !)

**EDIT**
Here **minimize cheating** means the sum of Rs calculated for all the students should be as minimized.

Comment: How large is m , n and k?

Comment: I dont know, but I think it does not matter here. We can assume some data of practical use (Exam hall) ie. m x n = 10 x 10, k = (1,100). But again I am more interested in asymptotic analysis, and a general solution for any set of m x n <= k.

Comment: Define "minimize cheating". Is the amount of cheating minimal if the sum of pairwise distances is minimal? Or the distance between adjacent students? If the latter, what constitutes adjacency? And in any case, what is the distance measure? Manhattan or Euclidean distance? Does a student occupy a cell completely or just the point in the center? Questions over questions

Comment: Here minimize cheating means the sum of Rs calculated for all the students should be minimized. For Distance, I am considering all the 8 cells around central cell are at equal distance. Yes, a student occupies a cell completely, i had mentioned it in first comment it self i.e m x n <= k.

Comment: @Arewegood what is the formula to use to calculate the distance between students? if a student occupies a cell completely, so k <= m x n, not the other way :)

Comment: Oh, yes. MY BAD !
It should be k <= m x n.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to pack k circles in a m by n plane? Why don't you simply use a hexagonal packing? Maybe check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing and related articles.

Answer (score 0):

I have thought of something but not using a matrix. Maybe it's useless but it can be fun.

So here's the algorithm:

Start with a random set of points in your bounded plane.

For each point P calculate the segment QR containig the two closest points Q and R to P.

Simultaneously move each point P along the axis of QR with a step size "s" proportional to 1/distance to closest point from P  (it can be either minus zero or plus zero according to the direction).

Do it again until a certain  function you choose is optimized (it can be the average distance or the distance of the
 closest points ) or do it again n times.

Repeat the entire process many times so that you will less likely get stuck at a local minimum.

So this is my attempt. I don't assure you that it will certainly work. But I've never seen any algorithm to do this. I study CS for fun so I'm definitely not an expert.

Comment: Your approach is good. But the question is in its simplest form, there is a classroom, in which seats are placed in the form of a matrix. Basically, I am interested in a matrix related answer. Give it a thought or you can start with my approach and add something. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> **How can we optimise it ?**

We cannot optimize your approach, because it isn't sufficiently specified, in particular how you calculate the so-called remoteness (R). Since the instructions "*For R, we can start with value t=max(m, n), and at each next cell we encounter at same level in BFS, we add t-level*" don't take into account whether the encountered cells are already occupied, this cannot possibly work as it is written.
Besides, the name *remoteness* seems misleading seeing that you seek to minimize it.

To understand the matter, let's consider the case m = n = k = 5, where the first 4 students (`*`) have already been placed at the corners of the matrix (which is optimal, I think you'd agree):

```
*...*
.....
.....
.....
*...*
```

What would be your R values for the empty cells (`.`)?

> **Are there better algorithms to do this ?**

In order to answer this question, we need a better definition of **minimize cheating** than the (somewhat reflexive) "*the sum of Rs calculated for all the students should be as minimized*".
Some have already been suggested by Niklas B. (*the sum of pairwise distances is minimal? Or the distance between adjacent students?* - but I think he meant **maximal**) and user46910 (*it can be the average distance or the distance of the closest points*). Let's consider taking one of them.

> **Has my starting cell X has something to do with final answer ?**

This also depends on the pivotal definition of **minimize cheating**, but I think we can assume that for every sane definition and k > 1, in an optimal placement at least one corner of the matrix will be occupied, while the middle won't always be (see e. g. the above matrix for k = 4). So, it should be preferable to start with occupying matrix<sub>0,0</sub> rather than matrix<sub>2,2</sub>.